# Raspberry Pi Pi cam module

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

I am new to raspberry pi and I am planning to buy a Pi cam with night vision. My question is does the slot in raspi board for the pi cam is all the same for all the version of raspberry pi?

Answer (score 2):

The Pi Camera socket is the same on all boards except for the Pi Zero which has a smaller socket.